# Program cannot connect to interactive broker

Tags: connection, interactive-brokers

I use the following class to handle IB connections:

```
from ib_insync import IB, IBC 
import asyncio

class IBGW(IB):

    def __init__(self, ibc_config, ib_config={}, connection_timeout=60, clientID=2):

        version = 978
        port = 4001
        self.ibc_config = ibc_config
        self.ib_config = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': port, 
                          'clientId': clientID, **ib_config}
        self.connection_timeout = connection_timeout

        self.ibc = IBC(978, **self.ibc_config)
        super().__init__()

    def start_and_connect(self):
        """
        Starts the IB gateway with IBC and connects to it.
        """

        self.ibc.start()
        wait = self.connection_timeout

        cnt = 0
        while not self.isConnected():
            # retry until connection is established or timeout is reached
            IB.sleep(0.5)
            wait -= 1
            cnt += 1
            try:
                self.connect(**self.ib_config)
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                if not wait:
                    raise TimeoutError('Could not connect to IB gateway')

    def stop_and_terminate(self, wait=0):
        """
        Closes the connection with the IB gateway and terminates it.

       :param wait: seconds to wait after terminating (int)
       """

       self.disconnect()
       self.ibc.terminate()
       self.sleep(wait)
```

When making a connection, I create an ibc_config dictionary like so:

```
ibc_config = {
            'gateway': True,
            'tradingMode': paper or live,
            'userid': ib_username
            'password': ib_password,
            'twsPath': some url,
            'twsSettingsPath': some path,
            'ibcPath': some path,
            'ibcIni': some path
    }
```

where "some path" contains the path to Java files containing the content for those parameters.

I can then pass this into an initialization call for the IBGW class

```
ib = IBGW(ibc_config=ibc_config)
```

and then, finally, connect to IB:

```
ib.start_and_connect()
```

However, this just returns an exception that I cannot connect to IB gateway. This has worked fine in the past, but now just does not connect. I even put it in a try catch statement to continually try and connect up to a few hundred retries, and it still does not connect. I am not sure what could have happened to suddenly cause connection issues to ib. Given the code above, does anyone know what might be happening?

If any more information is needed, I can add it. Thanks!

EDIT: The full exception I am getting is:

```
Exception: Could not connect to IB gateway.
```

The same exception occurs when I change the client ID to 0 or change the tradingMode to live.

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting? What happens if you set the client ID to 0? What happens if you set tradingMode to just live?

Comment: @MatthewScarpino I updated the question with more information

Comment: Strange. When you run IB Gateway, are all the status bars green? If you go to Configure >  Settings and then API > Settings, what does the window look like?